# C++ file not found when debugging from visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

My problem is that when doing

```
Shader* s = new Shader("Shaders\\test.vert", "Shaders\\test.frag");
```

or

```
Texture texture("test.png");
```

visual studio refuses to find them, yet when opening the .exe file everything is working properly. Doing

```
Shader* s = new Shader("C:\\Users\\Public\\Google Drive\\vs projects\\Engine\\Debug\\Shaders\\test.vert", "C:\\Users\\Public\\Google Drive\\vs projects\\Engine\\Debug\\Shaders\\test.frag");
```

does fix the problem for visual studio, but it's not really what I am looking for.

The way I am reading files:

```
    static std::string read_file(const char* path)
    {
        FILE* file = fopen(path, "rt");
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        unsigned long length = ftell(file);
        char* data = new char[length + 1];
        memset(data, 0, length + 1);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(data, 1, length, file);
        fclose(file);

        std::string result(data);
        delete[] data;

        return result;
    }
```

I have made sure I am running the project in debug(x86) mode. Any solutions?

Comment: What is shader?

Comment: @Danh do you mean the content of the shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the working directory of a C++ project in Visual Studio will be set to project directory when run from Visual Studio, instead of the directory which contains the executable. Source: [Project Settings for a C++ Debug Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcw4dzyf.aspx)

> **Working Directory**
>
> - Specifies the working directory of the program being debugged, relative to the project directory where your EXE is located. **If you leave this blank, the working directory is the project directory.** For remote debugging, the project directory will be on the remote server

Hence, the absolute path of `Shaders\test.vert` is

```
${path_to_your_project}\Shaders\test.vert
```

in your case, it's

```
C:\Users\Public\Google Drive\vs projects\Engine\Shaders\test.vert
```

or

```
C:\Users\Public\Google Drive\vs projects\Engine\{project_name}\Shaders\test.vert
```

if Engine is a solution folder

Simply move your file to the correct directory (the project directory), your code will work.

Comment: I assumed it was like C# on visual studio, where the debug/release folder contains the .vhost.exe file, my bad. Thanks, worked perfectly! :)